# Foreach loop table, sum per location and total of all location in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want to calculate the worth of all products per location and total of all locations combined.

so it looks like this

- location 1

  - product1, quantity, price
  - product2,  quantity, price
  - Total price  of all products  of location 1
- location 2

  - product3, quantity, price
  - product4,  quantity, price
  - Total price  of all products  of location 2
- location 3

  - product1, quantity, price
  - product3,  quantity, price
  - Total price  of all products  of location 3
- total price of all products of all locations

View:

```
<div>

    @foreach (var location in ViewBag.Location)
    {
        <h3><u>@locatie.LocatieName</u></h3>

        <div>
            <table class="table">
                <tr>

                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Product)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Quantity)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)</th>


                </tr>


                @foreach (var product in Model)
                {
                    if (product.LocationId == location.LocationId)
                    {

                        <tr>
                            <td>@product.Product</td>
                            <td>@product.Quantity</td>
                            <td>@product.Price</td>

                        </tr>
                        @Model.Sum(i=>i.Price)


                    }


                }

            </table>

        </div>

    }

</div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Worth()
        {
            ViewBag.Location = db.Location.OrderBy(c => c.LocationName).ToList();
            return View(db.Product.Include(c => c.Location).ToList());
        }
```

but somehow it only calculates the sum of the first location and repeats on the other tables.

Answer (score 0):

So an easy fix is just to do calculations in correct places:

```
@foreach (var location in ViewBag.Location)
{
    ...
    @foreach (var product in Model)
    {
    }
    // This filters products by current location, and sums up filtered products
    @Model.Where(product => product.LocationId == location.LocationId)
          .Sum(i => i.Price)
}

// This does not filter anything and just sum for all products
@Model.Sum(i => i.Price)
```

However do consider if you would like to review your view model. You are doing some non-trivial manipulations with the data, you might be better off doing them in controller and adding corresponding fields to the view.

Answer (score 0):

just declare a double in the 2nd loop:

you can do this like this

```
<div>

@foreach (var location in ViewBag.Location)
{
    <h3><u>@locatie.LocatieName</u></h3>

    <div>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                 @{
                  double sumPrice = 0;
                  }
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Product)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Quantity)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)</th>

            </tr>


            @foreach (var product in Model)
            {
                if (product.LocationId == location.LocationId)
                {

                    <tr>
                        <td>@product.Product</td>
                        <td>@product.Quantity</td>
                        <td>@product.Price</td>
                          @sumPrice+= produck.Price;
                    </tr>
                    @Model.Sum(i=>i.Price)


                }


            }

        </table>
             <tr> <td> total price </td> <td> @sumPrice </td> </tr>
    </div>

}
```